# Issue with lightning carousel

Tags: salesforce, carousel, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am facing some issues with a lightning carousel that I am building in lwc like it is showing only 5 to 6 images inside the carousel and remaining are not showing up. If there is any limitation for the number of images could you please suggest the best approach or alternatives like HTML slideshow or any other way to build a carousel for 1000's of images inside the carousel.
Here I am loading the images from the parent component.

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

export default class fcxmCarousel extends LightningElement {
  @api selectdImage;
  @api value;
}



<template>

              <div class="slds-m-around_medium">


                        <div class="container">                    

                   <lightning-carousel> 

                      <template for:each={value}  for:item="rows">


                              <lightning-carousel-image  width="100%" height="50%"  key={imageURL} src = {rows.imageURL}
                              header={rows.imageName}
                              description={rows.imageDescription}>
                             </lightning-carousel-image>



                       </template>

                    </lightning-carousel>
                </div>
               </div>
        <!--   </lightning-card> -->
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can only show 5-6 images using standard lightning-carousel component, for more details reefer this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:carousel